# Непонятный php файл

Tags: php

Работаю с cms opencart, в исходниках одного модуля нашёл такой php скрипт:

Что это такое, какое-то шифрование, если да, как это воспринимает сервер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это что-то зашифровано в base64. Посмотрите ниже, там должен быть скрипт, выполняющий "сам себя". В общем похоже на шелл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это файл от модуля "Автоматическая обработка прайс-листов". Он закодирован Ioncube Loader.